# Related to wireless channel variance?

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, covariance, channel

I am reading wireless research papers and found that mostly the wireless channel is considered to be Zero mean circularly symmetric Complex Gaussian (ZMCSCG) with variance 1 or 2 or 5 or 10 etc.

My query is why generally these values for channel variance are considered.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: *that mostly the wireless channel is considered to be Rayleigh distributed*; no, that's explicitly a Rayleigh channel. You might be looking at papers from the same field withing wireless communications, where that is a common channel. Under different circumstances, we consider very different channels!

Comment: Thank you Marcus sir for your response. I agree with you sir that "under different circumstances, we consider very different channels!". I would like to know the reason about "when we consider Zero mean circularly symmetric Complex Gaussian (ZMCSCG) channel then why in most papers variance of this channel is chosen to be 1 or 2 or 5 etc? Why not other values? "

Comment: I've never seen any of these choices; they're not very typical.

Comment: In general, something like that can only result **from a physical model or measurements**, and if you actually use anything but a symbolic variance $\sigma^2$, you need, as the paper using it, to argue why.

Comment: The questions you're asking are all different. Please focus on what you're actually interested in asking.  Please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/83633/edit) and update it with this information, and request the question to be re-opened.

Comment: When I first came to the US over 50 years ago, it puzzled me as to why the diameter of a small pizza was 10 inches, a medium pizza 14 inches, and a large pizza 17 inches. Fitting a straight line to the prices of these pizzas then provided an estimate of what was the fixed cost of producing a pizza and how much the ingredients cost. Your mileage may vary.....,